# Unity - Child moves faster than parent

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, parent-child

I'm using the following code to make my player move along with moving platforms, and it works in that it does indeed make you the child of the platform and move along with it while on it, however the player will move faster than the platform.
The platform is moving left then right between two points repeatedly, but the player moves quicker, so will slide along the platform, and you obviously might fall off therefore.

```
void OnCollisionEnter2D (Collision2D other) {
    if(other.gameObject.tag == "moving") {
        transform.parent = other.transform.parent;
    }
}

void OnCollisionExit2D (Collision2D other) {
    transform.parent = null;
}
```

Now I figure that this code is fine because as I have said you become the child of the platform and move along which is all this does.

Comment: is it possible that your player is moving at frames/second instead of meters/second?

Comment: if you are moving the parent AND the child both having a speed for themselves, the real speed of the child object is parent's speed + child's speed, IF you want both of them to move at the same speed, just move the parent object, since the child with move along

Comment: @Poncho - When just the parent is moving and I'm not providing any input, the child moves quicker.

Comment: @mehow - How would I know or have control over that? If I'm just making an object a child of something else, how is what you suggest possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Was going to delete this but I thought it'd be best just to leave it here in case anyone has the same issue.

After removing friction from the platform and the player, everything happens as expected, and I can move with the moving platforms without pressing anything.